# Expand/Retract all using .toggle jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of divs that I am expanding/retracting individually using .toggle and would like to have one button that will expand/retract all at the same time. So if one of them is already expanded/retracted it will stay expanded/retracted when clicked but the rest will expand/retract.

Here is what I am using for the individual divs:

```
$('.toggle-engine').click(function() {
    $('.specs-engine').toggle(400);
$(this).text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
return false;
});
```

Tried this for expand/retract all but if one of them was already expanded when I clicked expand all it retracted:

```
$('.expand-all').click(function() {
            $('.specs-body').toggle(400)
    $('.specs-engine').toggle(400)
    $('.specs-curb').toggle(400)
    $('.specs-cap').toggle(400)
    $('.specs-fuel').toggle(400)
    $('.specs-brakes').toggle(400);
$(this).text($(this).text() == '+ Expand All' ? '- Retract All' : '+ Expand All');
return false;
});
```

Here is the mark up:

```
<a class="expand-all" href="#">+ Expand All</a>
    <a class="toggle-engine" href="#">+</a>
    <div class="expand specs-engine"></div>
    <a class="toggle-body" href="#">+</a>
    <div class="expand specs-engine"></div>
```

Comment: Don't use toggle. Use slideUp() slideDown().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `show` or `hide` instead of `toggle` to force it to expand (show) or retract (hide) the elements.

Also, I recommend setting a common class to all the `.specs-...` elements, like `specs`, so for example:

```
<div class="specs specs-engine"></div>
<div class="specs specs-curb"></div>
... etc
```

So the JS would be:

```
$('.specs').click(function() {$(this).toggle(400);});
$('.expand-all').click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == '+ Expand All')
    $('.specs').show(400);
  else
    $('.specs').hide(400);
  $(this).text($(this).text() == '+ Expand All' ? '- Retract All' : '+ Expand All');
});
```

**EDIT**: to make the individual `+`/`-` images toggle, do something like:

```
$('.specs').click(function() {$(this).toggle(400);});
$('.expand-all').click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == '+ Expand All')
    $('.specs').show(400).find('img.plus, img.minus').hide().filter('img.plus').show();
  else
    $('.specs').hide(400).find('img.plus, img.minus').hide().filter('img.minus').show();
  $(this).text($(this).text() == '+ Expand All' ? '- Retract All' : '+ Expand All');
});
```

**EDIT2**: if I understand correctly:

```
$('.specs').click(function() {$(this).toggle(400);});
$('.expand-all').click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == '+ Expand All')
    $('.specs').show(400).find('.thelink').text('-');
  else
    $('.specs').hide(400).find('.thelink').text('+');
  $(this).text($(this).text() == '+ Expand All' ? '- Retract All' : '+ Expand All');
});
```

Anyway, you get it, it's a matter of selecting the right element and changing its text. jQuery does this for all the elements it finds with that single function call.

Comment: For the most part this worked - The one problem I am having is each of the individual buttons switch between + and - when clicked and I would like them to do this when I click on the expand all button. Above is the script I am using for the individual buttons and have used your script for the expand all.

Comment: Look at my edit. I'm not sure what your HTML looks like, but that could work.

Comment: Almost there; I have the + and the - inserted as text in each of the links and want them to display as text not images. What I used for the individual buttons was: $(this).text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');

Comment: Do something similar to adding the `specs` class for the toggle links, like `<a class="toggle toggle-engine" href="#">+</a>`, then you can use my last code (change `thelink` to `toggle`, of course)

Comment: It does not seem to be working. It looks like it should do the trick but is not.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to test if there are expanded using the function is(':visible')

```
if( $('.your-div').is(':visible') ){
    $('.your-div').toggle();
}
```

Comment: If you are checking for visibility, the toggle loses its purpose.